# How to properly encode "[" and "]" in queries using Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, httpclient, query-string

I've got a GET method that looks like the following:

```
 GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://host/path/?key=[\"item\",\"item\"]");
```

Such a path works just fine when typed directly into a browser, but the above line when run causes an IllegalArgumentException : Invalid URI.

I've looked at using the [URIUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/URIUtil.html) class, but without success.  Is there a way to automatically encode this (or to add a query string onto the URL without causing HttpClient to barf?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned `URIUtils` class has a method `encodeAll(str)` - so:

```
new GetMethod("http://host/path/?key=" 
       + URIUtil.encodeAll("[\"item\",\"item\"]"));
```

Comment: That results in another exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host parameter is null

Comment: @Jason Nichols - see my update. You have to encode only the parameter, not the whole uri

Comment: You know, I swear I tried that early on and it didn't work =)  Naturally it works now =)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use java.net.URLEncoder:

```
String myURL = "http://host/path/?" +
  URLEncoder.encode("key=[\"item\",\"item\"]", UTF-8);
```

Comment: And according to [this message](http://www.mail-archive.com/httpclient-users@hc.apache.org/msg02680.html) that is how it should be done in HttpClient 4.